# Show BLOB image in grid column with extjs

Tags: image, extjs, grid, extjs4, blob

I'm developing an application based on ExtJS and I have a form which uploads an image in BLOB format. Well, I have the image in database, but now I want to show it in a grid column, but I don't know how to do that. Some code:

Model:

```
Ext.define('pssp.model.icon.IconItem', {
  extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
  fields : [{
    name : 'id',
    type : 'int'
  }, {
    name : 'fileName',
    type : 'string'
  }, {
    name : 'iconBmp', => BLOB
    type : 'auto'
  }, {
    name : 'description',
    type : 'string'
  }]
});
```

View:

```
.
.
.
columns : [{
  xtype: 'gridcolumn',
  dataIndex : 'fileName',
  id:'fileName',
  name: 'fileName',
  text : this.i18nColFileName,
  flex : 1
}, {
  xtype: 'gridcolumn',
  dataIndex : 'description',
  id:'description',
  name: 'description',
  text : this.i18nColDescription,
  flex : 1
}, {
  xtype: 'gridcolumn', => This only show a String of bytes
  dataIndex : 'iconBmp',
  id:'iconBmp',
  name: 'iconBmp',
  text : this.i18nColIconBmp,
  flex : 1
}],
```

'iconBmp' show this:

> R0lGODlhFgAWALMAAB1ChF9vjzljwliE34Kl8b/I16PD+8zMzPDw7gAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACwAAAAAFgAWAAAIkgAPCBxIsKBBgQgSKlzIkCHChhAbPoxIEcHEihAvJixQwECBihoNGCBAksDHjAcWdhwgQMCAASYTClh40QDLly1hdpypsCbLhARykuSZ0GcAhQUCEMBJM6VCm0QRjGQJoKnKnzJbCgBQtadThS9Pgvya0OYAjBbJJnxpAKPGtQPEoozIcSzaiG/vptUr8aDfgwEBADs=

How I show this image ('iconBmp') as a real image??

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Well it looks like your image is coming back in valid Base64, which is good.  This probably isn't the best Ext JS way... not sure if there really is... but I would think you could do it with a combination of HTML and Ext JS's [`tpl`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-tpl), maybe like this:

```
, {
  xtype: 'gridcolumn', => This only show a String of bytes
  dataIndex : 'iconBmp',
  id:'iconBmp',
  name: 'iconBmp',
  text : this.i18nColIconBmp,
  flex : 1,
  tpl:'<img src="data:image/gif;base64, {iconBmp}" />'
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply, but I found the way to do it, I have posted 10 minutes ago :)

Comment: Yeah, when I was posting it hadn't existed yet.  Either way, two solutions... so it'll at least be a good reference for you and me :)

Answer (score 0):

I answer to myself, I have to write only a line, because data comes already in base64 format, this is:

```
xtype: 'gridcolumn',
dataIndex : 'iconBmp',
id:'iconBmp',
name: 'iconBmp',
text : this.i18nColIconBmp,
flex : 1,
renderer : function(value) {
  return '<img src="data:image/gif;base64,' + value +  '" />';
}
```

I write `gif` because my image is a gif image, in that line I had to check what format the image is.